# Vuejs 2 Passing prop object to child component and retrieving

Tags: components, vuejs2

I was wondering how to pass an object to a child component using props and retrieving. I understand how to do it as attributes but how to pass an object and retrieve the object from the child component? When I use this.props from the child component I get undefined or an error message.

Parent component

```
 <template>
        <div>
        <child-component :v-bind="props"></child-component>     
        </div>
    </template>

<script>
import ChildComponent from "ChildComponent.vue";

export default {
    name: 'ParentComponent',
    mounted() {

    },
     props: {
       firstname: 'UserFirstName',
       lastname: 'UserLastName'
       foo:'bar'
    },
    components: {
    ChildComponent
    },
    methods: {

      }
}
</script>

<style scoped>
</style>
```

Child component

```
<script>
<template>
   <div>
   </div>
</template>
export default {
    name: 'ChildComponent',
    mounted() {
    console.log(this.props)
  }  
}
</script>
```

Comment: 1) You aren't defining your props correctly on you parent component. 2) You can't pass your parent component's props via `v-bind="props"`. 3) If you are passing an object of props values to the child component via `v-bind` you still need to define those props in the child components. 4) "Retrieving" data from a child component is done via events. 5) Please read the documentation on [Vue components](https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/components.html)

Comment: I don't need to use v-bind. I got that from an example and try to use it. I'm looking for the correct way to achieve this. I'm looking over the Vue components doc now

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Simple as that:

**Parent component:**

```
<template>
  <div>
    <my-component :propObj="anObject"></my-component>     
  </div>
</template>

<script>
import ChildComponent from "ChildComponent.vue";

export default {
    name: 'ParentComponent',
    mounted() { },
    props: {
       anObject: Object
    },
    components: {
      ChildComponent
    },
}
</script>

<style scoped>
</style>
```

**Child component:**

```
export default {
  props: {
    // type, required and default are optional, you can reduce it to 'options: Object'
    propObj: { type: Object, required: false, default: {"test": "wow"}},
  }
}
```

This should work!

Take a look at props docs also: 
https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components.html#Props

If you want to sent data from the child to the parent as was already pointed in the comments you have to use events or take a look at 'sync' feature which is available in 2.3 +

https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components.html#sync-Modifier

Comment: What if you want to set a default value only to a property of your propObj? the default prop initialization would not trigger since the whole object prop isnt null.

Answer (score 0):

Yo can use **v-bind="object"** to pass an object as props to child component, besides you can access props in template using **$props**, therefore the answer is:

**Parent Component:**

```
<template>
  <div>
    <child-component v-bind="$props"></child-component>     
  </div>
</template>

<script>
  import ChildComponent from "ChildComponent.vue";

  export default {
    name: 'ParentComponent',
    props: {
      firstname: 'UserFirstName',
      lastname: 'UserLastName'
      foo:'bar'
    },
    components: {
      ChildComponent
    }
  }
</script>
```

**Child Component:**

```
<template>
  <div>
  </div>
</template>
<script>
export default {
  name: 'ChildComponent',
  props: ['firstname', 'lastname', 'foo'],
  mounted() {
    console.log(this.$props)
  }  
}
</script>
```

Answer (score -1):

Here's a simple solution for passing many props as an object into a component

#### Parent Component:

```
<template>
  <div>
    <!-- different ways to pass in props -->
    <my-component v-bind="props"></my-component>     
    <my-component :firstname="props.firstname" :lastname="props.lastname" :foo="props.foo">
    </my-component>     
  </div>
</template>

<script>
  import ChildComponent from "ChildComponent.vue";

  export default {
    name: 'ParentComponent',
    props: {
      firstname: 'UserFirstName',
      lastname: 'UserLastName'
      foo:'bar'
    },
    components: {
      ChildComponent
    }
  }
</script>
```

#### Child Component:

```
<template>
  <div>
  </div>
</template>
<script>
export default {
  name: 'ChildComponent',
  props: ['firstname', 'lastname', 'foo'],
  mounted() {
    console.log(this.props)
  }  
}
</script>
```

Comment: `console.log(this.props)` returns `undefined`