# How to pass axios response object from a parent component to child component using props in vue

Tags: vue.js, axios

I have a parent component named prospect.vue and a child component mandate.vue. I want to send the repsonse data object to child component mandate.vue using props how can i do it.

```
PROSPECT.VUE

    <div class="card-body dashboardContainer">
            <mandate/>
    </div>


export default {
  name: 'prospects',
  components: {
    mandate 
  },
  data() {
       return {
        sendata:{}
      } 
    },
    methods: {
                fetchData(){
                  axios.get('http://localhost:3000/data') .then((response) => {
                  //console.log(response.data);
                  this.sendata=response.data;
                  console.log(this.sendata);

                 })
               .catch(function (error) {
                console.log(error);
                 });
              }
    },
    created(){
    // Fetch Data
    this.fetchData();
}
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Vuejs 2 Passing prop object to child component and retrieving](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45174669/vuejs-2-passing-prop-object-to-child-component-and-retrieving)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There you go

```
PROSPECT.VUE

    <div class="card-body dashboardContainer">
            <mandate :data="this.sendata"/>
    </div>


export default {
  name: 'prospects',
  components: {
    mandate 
  },
  data() {
       return {
        sendata:{}
      } 
    },
    methods: {
                fetchData(){
                  axios.get('http://localhost:3000/data') .then((response) => {
                  //console.log(response.data);
                  this.sendata=response.data;
                  console.log(this.sendata);

                 })
               .catch(function (error) {
                console.log(error);
                 });
              }
    },
    created(){
    // Fetch Data
    this.fetchData();
}
}
```